# can import node-sass-json-importer in grunt-sass

Tags: node-sass

how can include node-sass-json-importer ?
i try to include node-sass-json-importer in includepaths in array way, with concat but no resuls...any idea? thanks for help

```
module.exports = {
dev: {
    options: {
        loadPath:['/'],
        sourceMap:false,
        style:'expanded',
        includePaths:require('node-bourbon').with('../node_modules/node-bourbon'),
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'patternlab/scss',
      src: ['**/*.scss'],
      dest: 'patternlab/source/css',
      extDot: 'last',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
}
```